# Open company data for Germany?

Tags: data-request, companies, germany, opencorporates

[OpenCorporates](http://opencorporates.com) doesn't have data for German companies (yet?).

Is there a source with open data for German companies?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/mask.do?Typ=n ? Not open (or free in all cases) but it seems to be all that's available according to http://registries.opencorporates.com/jurisdiction/de :-\

Comment: Also, perhaps OpenLEIs will have *some* info you were looking for? http://openleis.com/legal_entities/search/registered_country_code/DE

Comment: seems germany is there: https://opencorporates.com/companies/de?q=&utf8=%E2%9C%93 (although opencorporates is not so open for bulk data)

Answer (score 3):

Aswath Damodaran, Professor at Stern School of Business at New York University, has been compiling information on major corporations since 1998. His EU dataset contains data on 6,000 EU public corporations, including those in Germany.

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/data.html

Quandl has free datasets on current and historical stock prices for companies listed on the Frankfurt Stock Exchange:

https://www.quandl.com/FSE

Answer (score 1):

https://offeneregister.de provides basic German company information (companies and their officers) collected by OpenCorporates mainly in the period from June 2017 to January 2019, mainly from the Handelsregisterbekanntmachungen and to a lesser extent the Handelsregister (search results listings) for over 5,000,000 companies.