# Business register in Austria

Tags: data-request, finance, europe, opencorporates

I've tried to search for company register with API for registered businesses (including companies and self-employed people) in Austria, but with no luck. Does anybody know, if is there any?

Comment: please self answer if any of those on this question are useful: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3495/1511

Comment: Thank you @philshen, but the databases from the linked thread are not for Austria, but Germany. Also these databases don't contain ALL companies, just some of them, but I'd need to search among all businesses in the country (like in central register which exists in Czech Republic, Poland, Slovakia and many more countries).

Answer (score 1):

There is a *Firmenbuch* in Austria which officially registers all businesses. Unfortunately, retrieving data from that register is not for free. [Take a look here](https://www.registerauszug.at/), and you will see a price list after your search query. (If you know German, there are more information about the *Firmenbuch* [here](https://www.usp.gv.at/laufender-betrieb/firmenbuch/firmenbuchabfrage.html) at the Republic of Austria's *Unternehmensserviceportal*.)

If you are fine with aggregated data about the Austrian landscape of businesses, then you could take a look at [the relevant page of Statistics Austria](https://www.statistik.at/web_de/statistiken/wirtschaft/unternehmen_arbeitsstaetten/index.html). You might also find something at [Austria's Open Data Portal](https://www.data.gv.at/).